# PROGUARD fails when zip files are included in android project

Tags: java, android, proguard

I have zip assets in my /assets/ directory that I unzip during runtime. The project runs fine in debug mode but when I try to export it with proguard it always fails. The error that pops up has nothing to do with the the zipped but as soon as I remove them from the project proguard will compile the project.

Is there a way to tell it to ignore the assets directory or to ignore .zip files?

Comment: -keep class *.R  use this line in proguard